# Merge statement with two conditions in same CLAUSE alternative in Postgres

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, postgresql-9.4, cte

I was able to convert a Merge which has one condition in both MATCHED & UNMATCHED clauses using CTE. But not sure how to do (both `DELETE` & `UPDATE`), if I have two conditions in the same clause.
Below is the sample example:

```
SELECT * FROM source;

        ID     STATUS DESCRIPTION
---------- ---------- -----------------------
         1         20 Description of level 1
         2         10 Description of level 2
         3         20 Description of level 3
         4         10 Description of level 4
         5         20 Description of level 5

SELECT * FROM destination;

         1         20 Description of level 1
         2         10 Description of level 2
         3         20 Description of level 3
         4         10 Description of level 4
         5         20 Description of level 5
         6         10 Description of level 6
         7         20 Description of level 7
         8         10 Description of level 8
         9         20 Description of level 9
        10         10 Description of level 10
```

I have Merge implementation in ORACLE like below:

```
MERGE INTO destination d
  USING source s
    ON (s.id = d.id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET d.description = 'Updated'
    DELETE WHERE d.status = 10;

5 rows merged.

SELECT * FROM destination;

        ID     STATUS DESCRIPTION
---------- ---------- -----------------------
         1         20 Updated
         3         20 Updated
         5         20 Updated
         6         10 Description of level 6
         7         20 Description of level 7
         8         10 Description of level 8
         9         20 Description of level 9
        10         10 Description of level 10

8 rows selected.
```

If the above code will have as below:

```
MERGE INTO destination d
  USING source s
    ON (s.id = d.id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET d.description = 'Updated'
    DELETE WHERE d.status = 10
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (ID, STATUS, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (s.id,s.status,s.description);
```

Please help me how to re write the above code using WITH in Postgres.

Comment: Must rows with `status = 10` of new data be deleted too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Postgres (10) doesn't allow [MERGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html) statement. You can simulate it in this way:

> ```
> create table new_data (id int, status int, description text);
> insert into new_data values
> (1, 20, 'Description of level 1'),
> (2, 10, 'Description of level 2'),
> (3, 20, 'Description of level 3'),
> (4, 10, 'Description of level 4'),
> (5, 20, 'Description of level 5');
>
> create table destination (id int, status int, description text);
> insert into destination values
> ( 1, 20,  'Description of level 1'),
> ( 2, 10,  'Description of level 2'),
> ( 3, 20,  'Description of level 3'),
> ( 4, 10,  'Description of level 4'),
> ( 5, 20,  'Description of level 5'),
> ( 6, 10,  'Description of level 6'),
> ( 7, 20,  'Description of level 7'),
> ( 8, 10,  'Description of level 8'),
> ( 9, 20,  'Description of level 9'),
> (10, 10, 'Description of level 10');
> ```

> ```
> delete from destination d
> using new_data n
> where n.id = d.id
> and   n.status = 10;
>
> update destination d
> set    description = 'Updated'
> from   new_data n
> where  d.id = n.id;
>
> insert    into destination
> select    n.id, n.status, n.description
> from      new_data n
> left join destination d
> on        n.id = d.id
> where     d.id is null
> and       n.status <> 10;
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
>
> 3 rows affected
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from   destination
> order by id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | status | description            
> -: | -----: | :----------------------
>  1 |     20 | Updated                
>  3 |     20 | Updated                
>  5 |     20 | Updated                
>  6 |     10 | Description of level 6 
>  7 |     20 | Description of level 7 
>  8 |     10 | Description of level 8 
>  9 |     20 | Description of level 9 
> 10 |     10 | Description of level 10
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5e9efaa121a28f7376d4913ac29bf92f)*

**Using INSERT - ON CONFLICT DO**

> ```
> begin;
>
>     insert into destination
>     select n.id, n.status, n.description
>     from   new_data n
>     on conflict (id) 
>     do update
>     set description = 'Updated';
>
>     delete from destination
>     where  id in (select id from new_data where status = 10);
>
> commit;
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c69d96d95fca8dd11b56cf1c762476f3)*

**Using CTE**

> ```
> WITH 
>   u AS
> ( update destination d
>   set    description = 'Updated'
>   from   new_data n
>   where  d.id = n.id
>     and  n.status is distinct from 10
> ),
>   d AS
> ( delete from destination d
>   using new_data n
>   where n.id = d.id
>     and n.status = 10
> ),
>   i AS
> ( insert    into destination
>   select    n.id, n.status, n.description
>   from      new_data n
>   left join destination d
>   on        n.id = d.id
>   where     d.id is null
> )
> select 1 ;
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a94a700fa3d4c0be2dc64f5ad6e05234)*

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for a CTE.

Comment: @lakshmisowmya what should happen if `source` has a row with `status = 10` that doesn't exist in `destination`? Should it be inserted or not?